# Facebook Like Button Tag Missing error. How do I fix it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have facebook like on my mediawiki site and when I run it through the debugger http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I get the errors:

Admins And App ID Missing   fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Like Button Tag Missing og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Like Button Tag Missing og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Like Button Tag Missing og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

It also posts it as a 'recent activity' not a post with the image. 
How do I solve this?

Comment: Same problem here. It is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 28):

The "og:" tags must be in the head element of the HTML page that the like button refers to (usually the page the button is on). The Facebook debugger is telling you that they are not there. They should look like this:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My web page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://exmaple.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My site name" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This site is awesome!" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" />
</head>
```

You can use EITHER the fb:app_id or fb:admins, but not both.

I don't understand this, "It also posts it as a 'recent activity' not a post with the image. How do I solve this?" When the Like button is clicked a post is added to the user's timeline and the post may be visible to their friends depending on how they have configured privacy.

Comment: I never knew the either/or fb:app_id or fb:admins. How absurd. Several years ago, we were EXPLICITLY told by FB's documentation that we have to have admin IDs (but of course, FB wouldn't just GIVE you your app id; you had to go through a super-hacky get variable on fb.com to get it. Then I find out we can't have both and we've had it the whole time and consistently had problems with FB.